# Play different, full width background videos when hovering on overlayed text list

Tags: video, mousehover

I can't get this to work and can't understand why not.

As described in my title,
 I'm trying to display a full width video **layered underneath** a centred text list. The list needs to show the corresponding video underneath (text over video) at all times - by default the first item, then play when hovered on the text. The video then changes when hovering the next 'li' text, and so on. The li text also needs be a hyperlink when clicked (only the first one is here). Here is my code:

```
<div id="video-container">
  <video muted id="video" loop></video>
</div>
<ul id="text-list">
  <li data-video="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Line 1</a></li>
  <li data-video="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">Line 2</li>
  <li data-video="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4">Line 3</li>
</ul>
```

```
#video-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;

}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#text-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style-type: none;
}

#text-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

#text-list li:hover + #video-container #video{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```
const textList = document.getElementById("text-list");
const video = document.getElementById("video");

textList.addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName === "li") {
    video.src = event.target.dataset.video;
  }
});
```

So, I can see the video container is there and the links are doing something but nothing is displaying?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to try a different approach...

- Instead of listening for `textList` getting the Mouse-Over event..
- Assign the Mouse-Over on each `Li` element so that each becomes the event's specific target.
- When each one triggers the event, 
  You can then extract the `.value` of its ["data-video" attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).
   Or use `dataset` to extract the XXXX's value from your `data-XXXX` attribute).

Example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
#video-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

#video {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#text-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style-type: none;
}

#text-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

#text-list li:hover + #video-container {
  visibility: visible;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="video-container">

    <video muted id="video" loop>
      <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <ul id="text-list">
      <li onmouseover="on_mouseOver(this)" data-video="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"><a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Line 1</a></li>
      <li onmouseover="on_mouseOver(this)" data-video="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">Line 2</li>
      <li onmouseover="on_mouseOver(this)" data-video="https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mp4/sample_640x360.mp4">Line 3</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>

const textList = document.getElementById("text-list");
const video = document.getElementById("video");

function on_mouseOver( evt )
{
    //# NOTE attributes are in order of appearance within <tag> setup
    //# where currently shown tag setup means...
    //# attributes[0] == onmouseover
    //# attributes[1] == data-video

    
    //video.src = evt.attributes[1].value; //# get value for URL
    video.src = evt.dataset.video;
    video.load(); //# always "load" a new URL
    video.play();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Genius : ) Thanks so much for taking the time to help. Works perfectly. Cheers : )